# Jquery attr not working on IE 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to add an attr for the id and onclick, its working on firefox and chrome but for some reason it isn't working on IE 9 .
Any alternative or something is wrong with me code?

```
$(".extendedGridView tr td a").each(function (index) 
{
   if ($(this).html() == "Update") 
   {
       $(this).attr('id', 'insertButton');
       $(this).attr('onclick', "return Validate('extendedGridView')");
   }        
});
```

Comment: Can you try by changing `.html()` to `.text()`

Comment: its entering the if since i tried an alert and its working

Comment: why are you assignin same id to all links in that td and freebird is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use attr for this. Use

```
 this.id = 'insertButton';
 $(this).click(function(){return Validate('extendedGridView')});
```

Note also that checking a text using html() isn't going to work if there are returns or space or any tags. Prefer this test :

```
if ($(this).text().trim() == "Update") {
```

Then, be sure to have a different id for each element. It's unclear in your code if you're OK on this point but as you're using `each`, I'm afraid it's not. If what you need is to make your elements selectable more easily, use a class :

```
$(this).addClass('update');
```